# Postgres user can't create database when running django tests

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I've created a user, and given it the required privileges - i.e.

```
ALTER USER myuser CREATEDB
```

I can log in to psql as this user and create a database, however when I try to run django tests, I get "permission denied":

```
$ ./manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Got an error creating the test database: permission denied to create database
```

I have no such issues in another django project running off the same postgres instance, so something about my django project must be causing the error. The python and django versions are identical.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should be `myuser` when running tests. Maybe you should update `DATABASES` setting in settings.py for unit tests

Comment: Please check in the test settings if you are using the same `myuser`.

Comment: There are no test settings, in fact there aren't even any tests as yet, but I thought django just used the default user for tests anyway? How do I tell which user my tests are using?

Comment: I'm moron. It was a local settings file and the user in that file didn't have the required permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're actually running as the user you think you are - for example, check any local settings files

Answer (score 3):

Following steps may help you ,

```
CREATE DATABASE test_database;
CREATE USER tester WITH PASSWORD 'test_password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "test_database" to tester;
```